# I get confused about two lines source code in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in `./lib/express.js`,

```
function createApplication() {
    var app = function(req, res, next) {
        app.handle(req, res, next);
    };

    mixin(app, proto);
    mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);

    app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
    app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
    app.init();
    return app;
}
```

I know it will create an express app and return it to us, the app we receive is a function which will trigger when HTTP 'request' event happen, but what the purpose of the two lines code

```
app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
```

?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basically the shortcut for:

```
app.request = new req();
app.request.app = app;
```

The `__proto__` property sets the objects `prototype`. A `prototype` defines which methods an object inherits. For example `Array.prototype.slice` will be available at `[1,2,3].slice(1)`. The special thing about prototypes is that each instance of a prototype shares the same methods. So the methods of a prototype are not recreated which saves performance.

Yes and `app` is just a reference so that methods on the `request` object can access for example `app.settings` through `this.app.settings`.

Comment: thanks but I know what __proto__ means, what I wanna know is why the developer define the `app.request` object in express... I cannot find the place in source code uses `app.request`.

Comment: as I said you will need to look after "this.app" in one file which operates from "request"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what express is but this is what it looks like to me:

```
__proto__: req,
```

Sets "self" to the value of `req` (presumably the result of the request)

```
app: app
```

It's a reference back to the `app` value, in case you only pass the `request`/`response` object to another function. I.e.:

```
myFunction(app.response);
```

Now depending on your scopes, `myFunction` may not be able to find `app`, so the response object contains a reference to it, enabling you to interact with it regardless of what the scope of your function is.